# Did the Bush Administration threaten in 2006 to bomb Pakistan 'back to the stone age'?

Tags: pakistan

[Bush threatened to bomb Pakistan, says Musharraf](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2006/sep/22/pakistan.usa)  (The Guardian, 22 Sep 2006)

> "The intelligence director told me that (Mr. Armitage) said, 'Be prepared to be bombed. Be prepared to go back to the stone age'," Gen Musharraf was quoted as saying.

Was that a truth or Musharraf made that up?

Comment: https://historynewsnetwork.org/article/30347

Answer (score 6):

Since I doubt there were any minutes taken on that meeting, from the same article you have:

> Mr Armitage disputes the language used, CBS said, but he did not deny that Pakistan was put on notice to help America's war effort.

And that's probably as far as the truth can be established.

Also, a partially redacted version of the meeting's points, as recorded by the US, [was declassified](https://nsarchive.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/document-5-2001-09-14.pdf), and (of course) it doesn't support Musharraf's version.

Also, as [reported in a Pakistani newspaper](https://tribune.com.pk/story/85271/musharraf-admits-allowing-us-drone-surveillance/):

> Appearing in the Face-off programme, Musharraf said he was not sure who was telling the truth – his then DG ISI or Armitage.
>
> “Do you think that your DG ISI General Mehmood twisted Richard Armitage’s words?” he was asked. “No comments. I don’t know because this is one man’s word against the other and I don’t know,” was his response.

Comment: To save the next person looking it up: DG ISI = [Director-General of Inter-Services Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director-General_of_Inter-Services_Intelligence).